# VSCODE extension - How to show file save dialog

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is it possible in existing API, to show a dialog to user to save a file at custom location ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a proposed extension api (`saveEditor`) implementing `save` and `saveAs` so this simple code works:

```js
const activeUri = vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.uri;

// const res = await vscode.workspace.save(activeUri);   // no dialog

// const res = await vscode.workspace.saveAs(activeUri);    // dialog to enter filename plus overwrite warning 

// opens a dialog to enter filename plus overwrite warning if necessary
const res = await vscode.workspace.saveAs(activeUri)
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result);  // result is the Uri if successful
});
```

This can be tested now in Insiders.  Here is the resolved issue: [Have workspace.save and workspace.saveAs methods that return the URI](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/178713) and the api:

```
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
 *  Licensed under the MIT License. See License.txt in the project root for license information.
 *--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

// https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/178713

declare module 'vscode' {

    export namespace workspace {

        /**
         * Saves the editor identified by the given resource and returns the resulting resource or `undefined`
         * if save was not successful or no editor with the given resource was found.
         *
         * **Note** that an editor with the provided resource must be opened in order to be saved.
         *
         * @param uri the associated uri for the opened editor to save.
         * @return A thenable that resolves when the save operation has finished.
         */
        export function save(uri: Uri): Thenable<Uri | undefined>;

        /**
         * Saves the editor identified by the given resource to a new file name as provided by the user and
         * returns the resulting resource or `undefined` if save was not successful or cancelled or no editor
         * with the given resource was found.
         *
         * **Note** that an editor with the provided resource must be opened in order to be saved as.
         *
         * @param uri the associated uri for the opened editor to save as.
         * @return A thenable that resolves when the save-as operation has finished.
         */
        export function saveAs(uri: Uri): Thenable<Uri | undefined>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want custom path and data saving, I think the best you can do is:

```js
vscode.window.showSaveDialog({...options}).then(fileInfos => {
    // here you can use fs to handle data saving
    fs.writeFileSync(fileInfos.path, yourData)
});
```

This will prompt the user to enter a saving location and store the user choice in the `fileInfos` response.

Here is the doc: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#SaveDialogOptions

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your extension can use the `workbench.action.files.saveAs` command to bring up the save as dialog for the current file.

Comment: Does this also work for a previewHTML document? What if I want to save not as text but in a different form like svg graphs [in my vscode extension](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/master/images/antlr4-4.png)?

Comment: No. Html previews are unrelated. Your extension will have to wire up its own logic if you want to save those